# Ford figo warm starting issue duratorq 1.4 2011

Tags: ford, diesel, egr, hot-start, figo

I have a 2011 Ford figo duratorq 1.4 , and the car is having warm starting issues .

In the morning it starts without any effort , but when I go on a drive and stop . If I have driven for long enough,  the car won't start , if not then after 15 mins the car won't start . Having said so the car starts immediately if it is pushed and started.

Showed it to Ford service , they told me there is a problem with 2 injectors . I have checked the injectors and found out one injector was not working , had it replaced , but still the car won't start when hot.

Some said it might be an EGR issue but I am not sure !

Could anyone shed some light on this ?